# SQL Statement to Calculate DateTime Difference between Two Rows of the same Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, datediff

I have 2 columns in the Table1:  `Time_Stamp` and `RunTimeMinute`.  How can I subtract the `Time_Stamp` value where RunTimeMinute=0 from the `Time_Stamp` value corresponding to RunTimeMinute=1 (which would give me the time taken to get the machine running)?

```
Time_Stamp                      RunTimeMinute
    2016-03-01 04:32:10.0000000 1
    2016-03-01 04:33:11.0000000 2
    2016-03-01 04:34:13.0000000 3
    2016-03-01 04:35:15.0000000 4
    2016-03-01 04:36:16.0000000 5
    2016-03-01 04:37:18.0000000 6
    2016-03-01 04:38:20.0000000 7
    2016-03-01 04:39:22.0000000 8
    2016-03-01 04:40:23.0000000 9
    2016-03-01 04:41:16.0000000 0
    2016-03-01 04:45:36.0000000 10
```

Comment: Would you please provide at least the Math formula of the task you are trying accomplish in SQL?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: I want to take the time where RunTimeMintue = 0 and subtract it from the time where RunTimeMinue = 1.

Comment: So you will get a TimeSpan: please specify the time unit and the expected number. Best regards,

Comment: What version of SQL server? Does it support LEAD or LAG window functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish the task you have described (provided the `Time_Stamp` field is type of `DateTime` and `RunTimeMinute` is an Integer Number), you may use SQL `SELECT` Query/Subquery technique and `DATEDIFF()` function as shown in the following example:

```
SELECT [YourTable].Time_Stamp AS t1,
(SELECT YourTable.Time_Stamp FROM YourTable WHERE YourTable.RunTimeMinute=1) AS t0, 
DateDiff("n",[t0],[t1]) AS ElapsedTimeMin
FROM YourTable
WHERE ([YourTable].RunTimeMinute)=0;
```

`ElapsedTimeMin` will display result in minutes. You may specify the "datepart" of `DATEDIFF()` function as "s" to get result in seconds.

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DATEDIFF(mi,(cast(Time_STAMP) as Datetime),RunTime)

Answer (score 0):

For example we have a sample like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
  Time_Stamp datetime,
  RunTimeMinute int
)
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES                                         
('2016-03-01 04:32:10.000', 1),
('2016-03-01 04:33:11.000', 2),
('2016-03-01 04:34:13.000', 3),
('2016-03-01 04:35:15.000', 4),
('2016-03-01 04:36:16.000', 5),
('2016-03-01 04:37:18.000', 6),
('2016-03-01 04:38:20.000', 7),
('2016-03-01 04:39:22.000', 8),
('2016-03-01 04:40:23.000', 9),
('2016-03-01 04:41:16.000', 0),
('2016-03-01 04:45:36.000', 10),
('2016-03-01 05:31:10.000', 1),
('2016-03-01 05:35:11.000', 2),
('2016-03-01 05:37:13.000', 3),
('2016-03-01 05:39:15.000', 4),
('2016-03-01 05:41:16.000', 5),
('2016-03-01 05:46:18.000', 6),
('2016-03-01 05:48:20.000', 7),
('2016-03-01 05:51:22.000', 8),
('2016-03-01 05:53:23.000', 9),
('2016-03-01 05:55:16.000', 0),
('2016-03-01 05:57:36.000', 10),
('2016-03-02 05:34:09.000', 1),
('2016-03-02 05:35:14.000', 2),
('2016-03-02 05:36:11.000', 3),
('2016-03-02 05:37:18.000', 4),
('2016-03-02 05:38:20.000', 5),
('2016-03-02 05:39:38.000', 6),
('2016-03-02 05:40:40.000', 7),
('2016-03-02 05:41:12.000', 8),
('2016-03-02 05:42:32.000', 9),
('2016-03-02 05:44:11.000', 0),
('2016-03-02 05:47:38.000', 10)
```

Then we make this:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  Time_Stamp,
            RunTimeMinute,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RunTimeMinute ORDER BY Time_Stamp) AS rnum
    FROM Table1
    WHERE RunTimeMinute IN (0,1)
  )

SELECT  MIN(Time_Stamp) as StartTime,
        DATEDIFF(minute, MIN(Time_Stamp), MAX(Time_Stamp)) AS ElapsedTimeMin
FROM cte
GROUP BY rnum
```

And get this:

```
|               StartTime | ElapsedTimeMin |
|-------------------------|----------------|
| March, 01 2016 04:32:10 |              9 |
| March, 01 2016 05:31:10 |             24 |
| March, 02 2016 05:34:09 |             10 |
```